# quadratic residues and primes factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that if $(a,b)=1$ the number  $a^2+b^2$ don't have prime factors of the form
$4k-1$ and if also $(a,3)=1$ then the number $a^2+3b^2$ don't have factors of the form $3k-1$. We can say about the prime factors of $a^2+pb^2$?

I was trying to solve the first part: If a prime $p|a^2+b^2$ so $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, for this, is enough prove that $(-1|p)=1$, but I didn't get $x$ integer for this.

Any suggestions?? Thanks.

Comment: Work mod 4 and mod 3 respectively for the first 2 parts. QRs (quadratic residues) are $\{0,1\} \bmod 4$ and $\{0,1\} \bmod 3$. Generally just look $\bmod p$ for some appropriately chosen $p$.

Comment: Let $p$ be a prime factor of $a^2+b^2$. Since $\gcd(a,b)=1$, we can without loss of generality assume that $p$ does not divide $b$. Multiply $a^2+b^2$ by the inverse $c$ of $b$ modulo $p$. We get $(ca)^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$. You may know this is impossible if $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$.

Comment: I get it, thanks. Any suggestion for the general question?