# Generating prime factors of a certain congruence?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, fermat-numbers, mersenne-numbers

I'm aware that prime factors of $n^2+1$ take the form $4k+1$. It's also well known that factors dividing $\frac{a^p \pm 1}{a \pm 1}$ will be congruent to $2kp+1$. Fibonacci and some other recurrence relations constrain prime factors to $n \pm 1$ for relevant $n$.

Are there any other general tricks for generating numbers whose prime factors are constrained?

Comment: Your first one is special case of $x^2+y^2$ with $(x,y)=1$ having only prime factors of form $p=2$ or $p=4k+1$, see for example [quadratic residues and primes factors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732647/quadratic-residues-and-primes-factors) (you missed the $p=2$ part btw)